# Unable to relate the given sources/set up equation with the given info to solve quadrilateral problem

Tags: geometry, quadrilateral

> $ABCD$ is a square with area 625, $CDEF$ is a rhombus with an area of 500, area of the shaded region is $55x$. Find $x$ wherein $x$ is a single digit non-zero number.
>   [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$AB = BC = CD = AD = \sqrt {625} = 25$

$CD\times \text{alt rhombus} = 500$ so $\text {alt rhombus} = 20$.

Let the point where $BC$ intersects $FE$ be $X$ and consider the side of the triangle $XCE$.

$XC = 20$ and $CE = CD = 25$.

Can you finish it from there?

> $XE = \sqrt {CE^2 - XC^2} =\sqrt{25^2 - 20^2} = 15$

.

> Area of $\triangle XCE = \frac 12 20*15 =150$

.

> Area of the white area within the trapezoid $DFXC$ is $500 - 150=350$.

.

> Area of the shaded area is $625 - 350 = 275$

.

> $55x = 275$

.

> $x = \frac {275}{55} = 5$

Comment: I tried taking the portion of rhombus outside the square and put it inside, forming a rectangle of are 500 and height 20, therefore the area of the portion in the square uncovered by the rectangle is 625 - 500 = 125. But I did not know how to find out the area of the shaded region in the square onto where the triangle portion was put. Is there a way to continue from where I left? Or am I just complicating it?

Comment: "I tried taking the portion of rhombus outside the square and put it inside,"  Why????  *leave* it outside.  Figure out the area that is outside (it's a right triangle.. and you know what the hypotenuse and one of the legs is), subtract that area from the whole rhombus, and that will give you the area of the portion of the rhombus that is *inside* the square.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

$x^2 = 625$

$xy = 500$

$y^2 + z^2 = x^2$